# Where can I get a XAML path for an eyeball?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path, shapes

I have one for a Star that looks like:

```
  Data="M 61.3431396484375,0 C61.3431396484375,0 80.2991943359375,38.40919494628906 80.2991943359375,38.40919494628906 80.2991943359375,38.40919494628906 122.686279296875,44.56840515136719 122.686279296875,44.56840515136719 122.686279296875,44.56840515136719 92.01470947265625,74.46580505371094 92.01470947265625,74.46580505371094 92.01470947265625,74.46580505371094 99.25527954101562,116.68159484863281 99.25527954101562,116.68159484863281 99.25527954101562,116.68159484863281 61.3431396484375,96.75 61.3431396484375,96.75 61.3431396484375,96.75 23.430999755859375,116.68159484863281 23.430999755859375,116.68159484863281 23.430999755859375,116.68159484863281 30.67156982421875,74.46580505371094 30.67156982421875,74.46580505371094 30.67156982421875,74.46580505371094 0,44.56840515136719 0,44.56840515136719 0,44.56840515136719 42.3870849609375,38.40919494628906 42.3870849609375,38.40919494628906 42.3870849609375,38.40919494628906 61.3431396484375,0 61.3431396484375,0 z"
```

Comment: Ahaha that's one random request..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best strategy for **any** question like "Where can I get a XAML path for an XYZZY?" is to go find some clipart from Open Clip Art Library like:

- [Clipart search results for "eyeball"](http://www.openclipart.org/search/?query=eyeball)

pick which one you want, and then convert it from SVG format to XAML using Inkscape:

- [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)

Just load the SVG file and then save as XAML.

Here's a screenshot, I just converted one from the above search results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.xamalot.com/find/eyeball

Comment: Works fine :) There are lots of icons in Xamalot, just give a try.

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I get a XAML path for an eyeball?

Not from me. What exactly should that look like anyway?

By the way, the Data string you posted is just a compressed form, you can easily create [circles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.ellipsegeometry.aspx) and other shapes by settng a [`PathGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx) as the Data, see [*How to: Create a Shape using PathGeomertry*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745814.aspx) and use [`EllipseGeometries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.ellipsegeometry.aspx).

(Since an eyeball is made up of multiple shapes [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750593.aspx) might be of interest as well)

Comment: Hmm, should look like the all-seeing eye on the back of the dollar bill.